# B2B (LWR): Is language selector available in B2B commerce cloud?

Tags: digital-experience, b2b-lex

We are using B2B Commerce website based on LWR. While reading the official documentation https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.comm_components_other.htm&type=5 I got impression that "Language Selector" component is available in Digital Experiences. But I don't see it in the Components panel. Is it available or not?

[image: components panel in Digital Experience]

Comment: Did you enable at least two languages? Settings > Languages > Add Languages. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxLPa.png)

Comment: Yes, we have enabled all the languages we are using (EN, IT and FR).

Comment: Were you able to find it?

Comment: Unfortunately, we were not able to find the language selector in LWR Site.